# How to test a function in lisp and emacs

Tags: unit-testing, lisp, elisp, org-mode

How can I assert that `2012/08` (instead of Aug 2012) is returned from this function?

Thus I can start learning lisp on the job/with the function itself until the output satisfies.

I know some python unit testing (pytest) and am looking for something similar for lisp. However, my first attempt[0] `C-c eval-buffer` fails with `Invalid function: "<2012-08-12 Mon>"`

```lisp
(assert (= (org-cv-utils-org-timestamp-to-shortdate ("<2012-08-12 Mon>")) "Aug 2012"))

(defun org-cv-utils-org-timestamp-to-shortdate (date_str)
"Format orgmode timestamp DATE_STR  into a short form date.
Other strings are just returned unmodified

e.g. <2012-08-12 Mon> => Aug 2012
today => today"
  (if (string-match (org-re-timestamp 'active) date_str)
      (let* ((abbreviate 't)
             (dte (org-parse-time-string date_str))
             (month (nth 4 dte))
             (year (nth 5 dte))) ;;'(02 07 2015)))
        (concat
         (calendar-month-name month abbreviate) " " (number-to-string year)))
    date_str))
```

[0] https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UnitTesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(assert (= (org-cv-utils-org-timestamp-to-shortdate ("<2012-08-12 Mon>")) 
           "Aug 2012"))

(defun org-cv-utils-org-timestamp-to-shortdate (...) ...)
```

1. statements are executed in sequence, which means your function will only be defined after the assertion is evaluated. This is a problem because the assertion calls that function. You should reorder your code to test it after the function is defined.
2. you cannot compare strings with `=`, if you call `describe-function` (<kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd>) for `=`, you'll see that `=` is a numerical comparison (in fact, numbers or markers). For strings you need to use `string=`.
3. In a normal evaluation context, ie. not in a macro or a special form, the following is read as a function call:

   ```
   ("<2012-08-12 Mon>")
   ```

   Parentheses are meaningful, the above form says: call function `"<2012-08-12 Mon>"` with zero arguments. This is not what you want, there is no need to add parentheses here around the string.